# Can I delete a Entity that isn't in a list in Ursina Engine?

Tags: python, entity, ursina

I am making a game in Ursina Engine and I am trying to delete Entity by clicking it. Everything works fine until I click it. It won't destroy the Entity it just shutdowns the game

Here is my code, I have tried everything I can imagine.

```
from ursina.prefabs.health_bar import HealthBar
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
import time

def file_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path =sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception as e:
        base_path = os.path.abspath('.')
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller \
  import FirstPersonController

HB1 = HealthBar(bar_color=color.lime.tint(-.25),
                roundness=.5,
                scale=(1.5, .06))

def input(key):
    if key == '-' or key == '- hold':
        damage(5)
    if key == '+' or key == '+ hold':
        heal(5)

def damage(power):
    HB1.value -= power

def heal(value):
    HB1.value += value



player = FirstPersonController(
  collider='box'
)

enemy = Entity(model='cube', position=(2,2,6), color=color.dark_gray, scale=2, collider='box', texture='white_cube')

enemy.add_script(SmoothFollow(target = player, offset = [0,0,0], speed = 0.2))

floor = Entity(model='cube', position=(0,0,0), scale=(100,1,100), texture='grass', double_sided=True, collider='box')

def kill():
    if distance_xz(enemy, player) < 3:
        if enemy.hovered:
            if held_keys['left mouse']:
                destroy(enemy)  
def update():
    kill()
    if distance_xz(enemy, player) < 2:
        damage(2)
    if HB1.value == 0:
        quit()

sky = Sky()

app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code was just **DESTROYING** the enemy but, you have to **check if the enemy exists or not** everytime you check for distance between player and enemy or anything else, here is the full working code :

```
from ursina.prefabs.health_bar import HealthBar
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
import time

def file_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path =sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception as e:
        base_path = os.path.abspath('.')
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller \
import FirstPersonController

HB1 = HealthBar(bar_color=color.lime.tint(-.25),
                roundness=.5,
                scale=(1.5, .06))

def input(key):
    if key == '-' or key == '- hold':
        damage(5)
    if key == '+' or key == '+ hold':
        heal(5)

def damage(power):
    HB1.value -= power

def heal(value):
    HB1.value += value



player = FirstPersonController(
collider='box'
)

enemy = Entity(model='cube', position=(2,2,6), color=color.dark_gray, scale=2, collider='box', texture='white_cube')

enemy.add_script(SmoothFollow(target = player, offset = [0,0,0], speed = 0.2))

floor = Entity(model='cube', position=(0,0,0), scale=(100,1,100), texture='grass', double_sided=True, collider='box')

def kill():
    if enemy:
        if distance_xz(enemy, player) < 3:
            if enemy.hovered:
                if held_keys['left mouse']:
                    destroy(enemy)  
def update():
    kill()
    if enemy:
        
        if distance_xz(enemy, player) < 2: 
            damage(2)
    if HB1.value == 0:
        quit()

sky = Sky()

app.run()
```

Comment: I did not get it work. Do you have any other ideas how it might work? @Tanay

Comment: @AlienPlayerBoy This works perfect here, **You can try to `print` something instead of quitting the window**. This will give you an idea if the code is working.